# Why does `.each` return nil when called on a lazy enum after `.select`?

Tags: ruby, enums

I have a snippet of code that goes like this:

```
sent_messages = messages.lazy.reject { |m| message_is_spam?(m) }
                             .each   { |m| send_message(m) }
# Do something with sent_messages...
```

Some context: the `message_is_spam?` method returns true if the recipient of the message was messaged within the last 5 minutes. When `messages` contains several messages for the same recipient, the latter message will be considered spam only after the first message is sent. To ensure the latter message is considered spam, I lazily reject spam messages and send them.

I expect `.each` to return an array containing all items, but instead I get `nil`. `.each` always returns an array, except in this one scenario:

```
[].each {}                # => []
[].lazy.each {}           # => []
[].select {}.each {}      # => []
[].lazy.select {}.each {} # => nil
```

To add to the confusion, JRuby returns `[]` in all of the examples above.

Why does `.each` return nil when called like this? I can't find anything in the docs about it, and it's difficult to figure out what's going on in the C-code.

I've already figured out a way to completely bypass this issue; if I select up to 1 message per recipient (`messages.uniq_by(&:recipient)`), the operation no longer *needs* to be lazy. Nonetheless, this still surprises me.

Comment: I cannot tell why it returns `nil` but if you squeeze `.force` just before `.each` it returns what you want.

Comment: When called with a block, [`Enumerator#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) returns whatever the enumerator's block returns (in the doc's example, `each` returns `:method_returned`). So the actual question is: why doesn't `Enumerator::Lazy` provide a proper return value?

Comment: @Stefan `Enumerator::Lazy` is designed to create _no intermediate arrays_. What happens there is basically [a `foldl` of given functions](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/101/files#diff-efe8e903560c362c42e95673077801a6R1242), that’s why intermediate functions don’t return arrays, and, hence, all the intermediate results are `nil`s.

Comment: @mudasobwa it doesn't have to create an intermediate array. It could just return itself, i.e. the `Enumerator::Lazy` instance.

Comment: @Stefan it can’t return both a pointer to the reducer _and_ self :) To make functional folding to work, it is to return the former.

Comment: @mudasobwa both? If it can return `nil`, it could also return `self`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Stefan it is implemented in c and it in fact returns a pointer to a function, see the code I linked. It becomes nil in ruby only.

Comment: @mudasobwa do you think that `nil` was introduced accidentally or on purpose? I could easily implement a chainable `each`: https://gist.github.com/sos4nt/78396f0e97cf694a853c70225fc182c9

Comment: @Stefan your implementation is ruby and it basically ruins the whole idea. `Lazy::Enumerator` is implemented in `c` completely. The implementation returns a curried function. What happens when one chains two `select`s, the `fun(fun(arg))` is passing the argument through a chain of functions, there is _no intermediate `self`_. Once the chain is ended, the call to actual block happens. That’s why there is (for instance) no `enum_for` for `select`. `select` requires a block, because for each iterated value, the chain of functions will be called, not results are chained.

Comment: This looks like a violation of the contract of `each`, which is supposed to return `self`. This can only possibly be true if `self` is `nil`, but that can't be because `nil` doesn't respond to `each`. I would say it is a bug.

Comment: @axiac that will change the behavior of this snippet of code, because `send_message` can cause another message in `messages` to be considered spam. I've added some context in the question for clarification.

Comment: @JörgWMittag would you mind to point out where “the contract of `each`” states it’s “supposed to return `self`”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Possible explanation

One of the purposes of [`Enumerator::Lazy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) is to avoid having a huge (or possibly infinite) array in memory. This could explain why [`Enumerator#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) doesn't return the desired array.

Instead of risking running out of memory with a huge array, methods like [`Lazy#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-reject) prefer returning `nil` as an alternative value (the one returned by `each` afterwards) :

```
return lazy_add_method(obj, 0, 0, Qnil, Qnil, &lazy_reject_funcs);
```

In comparison, `Enumerable#lazy` returns :

```
VALUE result = lazy_to_enum_i(obj, sym_each, 0, 0, lazyenum_size);
```

I suspect that the distinct arguments :

- `Qnil` for `reject`
- `sym_each` for `lazy`

are the reason why :

- `[].lazy.each {}` returns `[]`
- `[].lazy.select{}.each {}` returns `nil`.

Still, it doesn't seem consistent for `each` to return an array or `nil`
.

## Alternatives

#### each

A more verbose alternative for your code could be :

```
messages = %w(a b c)
messages_to_send = messages.lazy.reject{|x| puts "Is '#{x}' spam?"}
messages_to_send.each{ |m| puts "Send '#{m}'" }
# Is 'a' spam?
# Send 'a'
# Is 'b' spam?
# Send 'b'
# Is 'c' spam?
# Send 'c'
```

`Lazy#reject` returns a `Lazy` Enumerator, so the second `message_is_spam?` will be executed after the first `send_message`.

There's one problem though, calling `to_a` on the lazy enumerator will call `reject` again :

```
sent_messages = messages_to_send.to_a
# Is 'a' spam?
# Is 'b' spam?
# Is 'c' spam?
```

#### `map` and modified method

You could also return `m` at the end of `send_message` and use [`Lazy#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-map):

```
sent_messages = messages.lazy.reject { |m| message_is_spam?(m) }
                             .map { |m| send_message(m) }.to_a
```

`map` should reliably return the desired Enumerator::Lazy object. Calling [`Enumerable#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) ensures that `sent_messages` is an array.

#### `map` and explicit return

If you don't want to modify `send_message`, you could return `m` explicitely at the end of each `map` iteration :

```
messages = %w(a b c)

sent_messages = messages.lazy.reject{ |m| puts "Is '#{m}' spam?" }
                             .map{ |m| puts "Send '#{m}'"; m }.to_a   
# Is 'a' spam?
# Send 'a'
# Is 'b' spam?
# Send 'b'
# Is 'c' spam?
# Send 'c'

p sent_messages
# ["a", "b", "c"]
```

#### Modified logic

Yet another alternative would be to redefine your logic without `lazy` :

```
sent_messages = messages.map do |m|
  next if message_is_spam?(m)
  send_message(m)
  m
end.compact
```

Comment: The collection doesn't have to be huge. Maybe `message_is_spam?` is just an expensive operation and the OP wants to send each non-spam message as soon as possible instead of waiting for all checks to complete. BTW, I think `sent_messages` is supposed to be an array, not an `Enumerator::Lazy` instance.

Comment: The first alternative solution will not work, because `send_message` can affect the outcome of later `message_is_spam?` calls. I've edited the question to clarify this. The second solution works fine as a workaround, but requires the reader to know about `send_message`'s return value to fully grasp the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use .map it returns the expected result, why each gives nil in this case is unclear.

```
 p [1,2,3].lazy.select{|x| x>1 }.map{|x| x}.to_a #=> [2, 3]
```

or just

```
p [1,2,3].lazy.select{|x| x>1 }.to_a #=> [2, 3]
```

On this subject, read this http://railsware.com/blog/2012/03/13/ruby-2-0-enumerablelazy/ blog

Comment: That returns an empty array, because `nil.to_a` is `[]`. You have to move the `.to_a` before `.each`

Comment: It also doesn't answer the question. `[1,2,3].lazy.select{|x| x>1 }.each{|x| p x}` evaluates each element but still returns `nil`.

Comment: @EricDuminil that is because `nil.to_a #⇒ []` as Stefan pointed out above.

Comment: `.each`, when given a block, already evaluates lazy enumerators. Example: `[1,2].lazy.each { } # => [1,2]`